# While Loop Problems: Math in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I wrote a procedure that adds all numbers from 1 to a given number (Input 3- you get 6, 4 you get 10, etc). I thought it was a fun little piece of code, so I thought I would turn it into a while loop (you start the loop, and it outputs everything up until a specific number.

Question: 
What do I need to do to turn this into a while loop?

What I have

```
CREATE Procedure MATH 
@InNumber INT,  
@OutNumber INT OUTPUT 

AS
BEGIN

WHILE @InNumber <= 0
RETURN @OutNumber -1;

BEGIN 
  SET @OutNumber=((@InNumber)*(@InNumber+1))/2)
END

 PRINT @OutNumber;
END
```

Comment: `SET @OutNumber=((@InNumber)*(@InNumber+1))/2)` is already using Gauss's formula for summing integers. Why do you think you need a while loop?

Comment: "As long as `@InNumber` is less than zero keep returning one less than the initial value of `@OutNumber` as the completion status. Start a compound statement to contain a single statement that computes a value using LISP. (Or the author is paid by the parenthesis.) End the compound statement. Print the computed value." There are some opportunities to clean up this bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a sound SQL design - use a [tally table](http://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/) instead like this:

```
with E1(N) AS ( 
  select N from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1) )E1(N)
),                                             --10E+1 or          10 rows
E2(N) as (select 1 from E1 a cross join E1 b), --10E+2 or         100 rows
E4(N) as (select 1 from E2 a cross join E2 b), --10E+4 or      10,000 rows
E8(N) as (select 1 from E4 a cross join E4 b), --10E+8 or 100,000,000 rows
cteTally(N) as (
  select top (@InNumber)
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
  from E8
)
select sum(N) 
from cteTally;
```

Tally tables are so useful that in most databases a permanent tally table exists with a number of rows that handles most applications for that database. For instance, in a database supporting mortgage calculations, 11,000 rows is  sufficient to handle one row per day of a 30 year mortgage (as 30 * 366 = 10,980).

Then with a permanent tally table called *dbo.Tally* available the code becomes simply:

```
select sum(N) 
from dbo.Tally
were N <= @InNumber;
```

Using WHILE loops in SQL is a horrendous code smell. They may occasionally be necessary, but in over 30 years programming I can count on the fingers of one hand the number of times I have had to use one.

**Update**:

Of course, as a commentator noted above, no matter how efficient this implementation is truly sound design would use a closed-form formula (Gauss's in this instance) whenever one is known to exist.